# Visual C++ read entire file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, binary, ifstream, winsock2

For days I have been trying to read an entire PNG into a string, so I can upload it to a server via winsock2, it appears to stop reading the file after a few characters or a some sort of line break, is there any particular reason and a way of solving it.

I have tried many many solutions and this is now starting to drive me insane. The current code I am using is as follows

```
std::ifstream in ("some.png", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate );
std::string contents;
if (in)
{           
    in.seekg(0, in.end);
    contents.resize(in.tellg());
    in.seekg(0, in.beg);
    in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
    in.close();
    length = contents.size();        
}
```

I have no idea what the problem could be, as I am relatively new to c++, I have trolled through google for days with no working solution.

Please help

UPDATE code posting to the server

```
    WSADATA wsa;

        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    return;


    SOCKET fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

            if (fd < 0)     
                throw;

            SOCKADDR_IN service;

    service.sin_family    = AF_INET;
    service.sin_port      = htons(80);
    LPHOSTENT host        = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

            if (!host)          
                throw;

            service.sin_addr = *((LPIN_ADDR)*host->h_addr_list);

            if (connect(fd, (SOCKADDR *)&service, sizeof(service)) < 0)     
                throw;

    int length ;

    std::ifstream in (CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativePath("back.png"), ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate );
    std::string contents;

            if (in){

            in.seekg(0, in.end);
        contents.resize(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, in.beg);
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
        in.close();
        length = contents.size();
    }else

        std::string str =
        "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: metapps.co.uk\r\n"
        "Accept: */*\r\n";

        char buffer1 [50];  
        str.append(  "Content-Length: 121\r\n" );
        str.append(  "\r\n" );

        str.append(  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tmp\";filename=\"photo.png\"\r\n" );
        str.append(  "Content-Type: image/dds\r\n" );
        sprintf (buffer1, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", length);
        str.append( buffer1 );
        str.append( contents    );
        str.append(  "\r\n\x01A\r\n" );

        // send str ...
        send(fd, str.c_str() , strlen( str.c_str() ) +1 , 0);
        char ret[1024];

        recv(fd,ret,strlen(ret),0);

        closesocket(fd);
        WSACleanup();
}
```

---

Update 2

Its something to do with the Null terminator string and the append method

If I do

```
str.append( "he\0llo"   );
```

The server will only show "he"

If I do

```
str.append( "hello" );
```

I get hello, hopefully this info, can lead to a solution

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to print this string to see if it is correct?  That won't work as it will stop at the first null character it finds, and there are likely to be quite a few in a png image.

Comment: I am printing it to the output window, but the same result is also inside of the uploaded data too.

Comment: I suspect all the data is there, but as I said, printing it as a string won't work because of the embedded null characters, and that's how the string is displayed in the watch window in Visual Studio unless you click the plus to view it as an array.  I bet if you write the data to a new file and compare them they will be identical.

Comment: Your current code looks about right. Can you describe what you think isn't working? Obviously, a .PNG file is not "human readable", so it will look like gobbledegook to a human.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Are you sure? Printing a std::string should work. But of course, it will still look like crazy binary data, because that is what it is. But `std::string`s are not NULL terminated, and will (most likely) print NUL characters and other such things.

Comment: The server accepts the request fine but the message body in the response only contains something along the lines of "?png" which cant be right as I can see the content length is around 1000+ , I dont get all expected gobbledegook

Comment: So how are you actually sending the data to the server? How is the server expecting the data, by what method does it read the data? Does it need special encoding for special characters?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I am using winsock2 using string append for the header request as will as string append for the read data via contents.c_str()

Comment: @MatsPetersson You're correct, that `cout << string` would print past the null characters, but, without details on how he was determinng the data was missing I guessed that he was using something like `printf` or viewing the data in the watch window in vc++.  I tested this code and it does read the whole file.  Of course, in a properly formed png file the first null is around 10 bytes in where the size of the IHDR chunk is stored.

Comment: @blakey87: Can you post the sending code - I suspect it's wrong, but without seeing it, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I just tried adding a break point then checked the string, it does in fact have all the expected data in there,so I wonder why is in turn is not being sent to the server, Im also not sure if I have to encode the data in any special way, Im just doing a raw http post request to an apache server running PHP

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that is constructing the data you're sending.

Comment: I have edited the question showing the full code I am using to send the request to the server

Comment: With your `recv()` call you're asking for, and promptly throwing away, up to 1024 chars, and no more immediately after the `send()`. Did you *intend* to do that?? Furthermore, you're using `strlen(ret)` and the length-specifier for the read. Um.. `ret` is an uninitialized array of char. Not only is that the wrong function to determine its size, its outright *undefined behavior*. For this *specific* case `sizeof(ret)` is what you want.

Comment: @WhozCraig Im just starting out with c++ I wasbnot sure how to get the correct length of the response

Comment: Ah, ok.  `strlen( str.c_str() ) +1` won't work, it'll stop at the null.  You could use `str.size()` instead.

Comment: Honestly you shouldn't be using `std::string` for this in the first place. For sending and receiving socket data you should be using `std::vector<unsigned char>` (at least I sure would). You can toy with the bytes once you have them (whatever they are).

Comment: Don't you just hate it when you get the OP to post the offending code, go look at another problem, and then the question has been answered... :(

Comment: @MatsPetersson You got Duck ninjad. :)

Comment: @blakey87: Generally, you read in a fixed sized header which tells you how long the rest of the message is.  Then you allocate that much memory, and read in the rest of the messgae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

The header Content-length I was sending were a fixed length of 121

```
       str.append(  "Content-Length: 121\r\n" );
```

So the server was therefore truncating the message body to this length, I had no idea the server took this value so seriously, if it were too big it would also throw a 500 error.

Sending the correct length for the message body fixed it.

I also separated the headers from the message body and used a

```
std::vector<char>
```

to store the message body as per @youdontneedtothankme

Thanks for all replies and comments, helped me get to the bottom of the issue after one long week of frustration, my life can now move on lol :)

Stackoverflow FTW!

Answer (score 3):

```
    send(fd, str.c_str() , strlen( str.c_str() ) +1 , 0);
        char ret[1024];
```

`strlen( str.c_str() ) +1` will tell you the position of the first 0 byte in the output, and is NOT the length of the string.  The length of the string is best optained via `str.size()` instead.

---

Also, as [WhosCraig mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412110/visual-c-read-entire-file/18412661#comment27047670_18412110), you're calling `strlen(ret)` where `ret` is uninitialized.  Instead, use

```
  std::array<char, 1024> ret;
  recv(fd,ret,ret.size(),0);
```

or potentially something more dynamic.

Comment: When using str.size() I get the following
Error 4 error C3867: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::size': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::size' to create a pointer to member

Comment: Actually ignore that  strlen( str.size() ) doh!

I still get the same result from the server though

Comment: @blakey87: Go through the code and remove _all_ `strlen` from it.

Answer (score 1):

One way<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
std::ifstream in("some.png", ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> contents(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), {});
```

Another

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << in.rdbuf();
std::string contents = iss.str();
```

As others have noted, it's usually not necessary to have the full contents in memory at a single time, though. It leads to problems with scalability. Avoid it if at all possible.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> If your compiler is standards challenged, break it up:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> f(in), l;
std::vector<unsigned char> contents(f, l);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `&contents[0]` to get the address of the internal buffer used by the string. As far as I know, this buffer is not guaranteed to be sequentiental, or even have the right size before you call .c_str(), so you just can't pass the address around.

Use `std::vector<char>` or `std::array<char, n>` for raw binary data. They are allways guaranteed to have sequential buffers.

Oh, and by the way, there is no need to read the whole file into one big buffer. Just read and write it piecewise.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I would use `std::vector<char>`, thanks

Comment: In your client, where you read the png-file, just swap `std::string` with `std::vector<char>`. To access the internal buffer, use `&contents[0]` as you did before.